# access 2003 to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I search a way to export an access 2003 database to sql server express 2008.

- the export is on la (other computer than the server).
- the computer have office 2003.
- the computer doesn't have admin right (cant install things who needs admin)

access sql migration said that he cant(because 2008 is too new)

whats the better(easyer and shortway) to export the db?

Comment: I try SSMA but theres somes thing he need to install/change with admin right, I try to ignore, but the program not start, do error, nothing.

Comment: How big is the database?  How many objects?

Comment: 4small table, 1 with 4000rows, 1 with 250000rows (­~12col)

Comment: If that's it then why can't you just export to a flat file and load from that?

Comment: its more the How load it? from my desktop

Comment: You don't have SSMS on the computer with the access db?

Comment: no, I cant install it, he need admin right

Comment: Then this is a ludicrous and impossible scenario. If you can't install anything on the system with the mdb, and none of your current tools will work, what do you want us to tell you?  You are basically asking **"How can I go 100 mph without using a car or anything but my legs?"**

Comment: 1 - of course its a possible senaria, that's what appening when you are in a real big company (often). 

2 - I didn't said that I cant install anything, I just cant install if it need to use register, or ask admin right, or install on drive C (I can install in my doc and setting who is on another drive).
the problem is that microsoft apps need to be install with admin right, so each time, he just said that I dont have right and stop. So I search a program portable or existing code, or an apps that I can install.

Comment: I will probably create my own code to upload it.

Comment: The scenario is "possible" in that I'm sure it's happening, but it's impossible to resolve given the constraints.  You need to be able to install software.  Talk to your IT department.

Comment: IT is 300 miles away, and I know they will say no: security failure.
And I can install software, just not theses one.

Comment: If you can only "install" software that doesn't use `ProgramFiles` or the registry, you're not installing anything.  You can COPY stuff to your MyDocuments.  Also, what does distance have to do with it?  they don't have any kind of remoting?  They won't install a tool you need to do your job?

Comment: no they will said prove that you cant do something else, that will take weeks, and I need a tech (who's here 6days/month). Theres so much things that finally its Find a way by yourself. and its not mydoc but document and settings. technicly you right, its a copy, (all file of a prog is on a folder or in appsData). But its call install (like you install firefox, but he doesnt need admin right and you can put it wherever you want)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Import/Export wizard with SQL Server. I came across a very good write-up (nice pretty pictures) [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/transferring-data-ms-access-2003-to-sql-server-2008) on it.

Comment: you need to be on the server, I cant do that

Comment: No you don't. I have done it with Excel with no issue. SQL Server server and my desktop within the same network but I was not on the server. Excel file (source) was on my desktop.

Comment: how did you get Import and Export Data on your desktop? need to install with admin right. cant do that

Comment: Ah, yeah you will have to be on a computer that has SQL Server Management Studio installed.

Comment: I cant do that!